# Filter and loop through array of JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript

```
var data= [
{"area":"1","location":"01051A","aisle":"1","sequence":12354,"x":13,"y":1338},
{"area":"1","location":"01071A","aisle":"1","sequence":12355,"x":13,"y":1437},
{"area":"1","location":"01081A","aisle":"1","sequence":12356,"x":173,"y":1437},
{"area":"1","location":"02021A","aisle":"2","sequence":12473,"x":401,"y":1092},
{"area":"1","location":"02022A","aisle":"2","sequence":12472,"x":401,"y":1140},
{"area":"1","location":"02031A","aisle":"2","sequence":12471,"x":241,"y":1191},
{"area":"1","location":"02032A","aisle":"2","sequence":12470,"x":241,"y":1239},
{"area":"1","location":"02041A","aisle":"2","sequence":12469,"x":401,"y":1191},
{"area":"1","location":"02042A","aisle":"2","sequence":12468,"x":401,"y":1239},
{"area":"1","location":"03101A","aisle":"3","sequence":12476,"x":629,"y":1437},
{"area":"1","location":"03102A","aisle":"3","sequence":12477,"x":629,"y":1485},
{"area":"1","location":"03111A","aisle":"3","sequence":12478,"x":469,"y":1536},
{"area":"1","location":"03112A","aisle":"3","sequence":12479,"x":469,"y":1584}
]
```

I have this set of data. What is the best way to filter by each 'aisle' and work with that set? 
for example , I want to find out the min and max sequence for aisle 1, do something then aisle 2... do something and so on...

currently I'm getting the min, and max coordinates for all data using something like this.

```
 var minX = Math.min.apply(null, data.map(function(a){return a.x;})),
 maxX = Math.max.apply(null, data.map(function(a){return a.x;})),
   minY = Math.min.apply(null, data.map(function(a){return a.y;})),
   maxY  = Math.max.apply(null, data.map(function(a){return a.y;}));
```

But I also need to find the min , max and for each set so I can get coordinates and draw labels on the screen.

I was thinking into looping then create an array of unique aisles then loop the data again but I think there is go to be a better way.

Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czcz/ogryw6zf/) that I'm working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an object for collecting `aisle`, `x`, `y` and their `min` and `max` values.

```js
var data = [{ area: "1", location: "01051A", aisle: "1", sequence: 12354, x: 13, y: 1338 }, { area: "1", location: "01071A", aisle: "1", sequence: 12355, x: 13, y: 1437 }, { area: "1", location: "01081A", aisle: "1", sequence: 12356, x: 173, y: 1437 }, { area: "1", location: "02021A", aisle: "2", sequence: 12473, x: 401, y: 1092 }, { area: "1", location: "02022A", aisle: "2", sequence: 12472, x: 401, y: 1140 }, { area: "1", location: "02031A", aisle: "2", sequence: 12471, x: 241, y: 1191 }, { area: "1", location: "02032A", aisle: "2", sequence: 12470, x: 241, y: 1239 }, { area: "1", location: "02041A", aisle: "2", sequence: 12469, x: 401, y: 1191 }, { area: "1", location: "02042A", aisle: "2", sequence: 12468, x: 401, y: 1239 }, { area: "1", location: "03101A", aisle: "3", sequence: 12476, x: 629, y: 1437 }, { area: "1", location: "03102A", aisle: "3", sequence: 12477, x: 629, y: 1485 }, { area: "1", location: "03111A", aisle: "3", sequence: 12478, x: 469, y: 1536 }, { area: "1", location: "03112A", aisle: "3", sequence: 12479, x: 469, y: 1584 }],
    values = Object.create(null);

data.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!values[o.aisle]) {
        values[o.aisle] = { x: { min: o.x, max: o.x }, y: { min: o.y, max: o.y } };
        return;
    }
    ['x', 'y'].forEach(function (k) {
        ['min', 'max'].forEach(function (m) {
            values[o.aisle][k][m] = Math[m](values[o.aisle][k][m], o[k]);
        });
    });
});
        
console.log(values);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var aisles = {};

data.forEach(d => {
  if (!aisles[d.aisle]) {
    aisles[d.aisle] = {
      maxX: d.x,
      minX: d.x,
      maxY: d.y,
      minY: d.y
    };
  } else {  
    aisles[d.aisle].maxX = Math.max(aisles[d.aisle].maxX, d.x);
    aisles[d.aisle].minX = Math.min(aisles[d.aisle].minX, d.x);
    aisles[d.aisle].maxY = Math.max(aisles[d.aisle].maxY, d.y);
    aisles[d.aisle].minY = Math.min(aisles[d.aisle].minY, d.y);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another flavor using Array.reduce

```js
var data = [{ area: "1", location: "01051A", aisle: "1", sequence: 12354, x: 13, y: 1338 }, { area: "1", location: "01071A", aisle: "1", sequence: 12355, x: 13, y: 1437 }, { area: "1", location: "01081A", aisle: "1", sequence: 12356, x: 173, y: 1437 }, { area: "1", location: "02021A", aisle: "2", sequence: 12473, x: 401, y: 1092 }, { area: "1", location: "02022A", aisle: "2", sequence: 12472, x: 401, y: 1140 }, { area: "1", location: "02031A", aisle: "2", sequence: 12471, x: 241, y: 1191 }, { area: "1", location: "02032A", aisle: "2", sequence: 12470, x: 241, y: 1239 }, { area: "1", location: "02041A", aisle: "2", sequence: 12469, x: 401, y: 1191 }, { area: "1", location: "02042A", aisle: "2", sequence: 12468, x: 401, y: 1239 }, { area: "1", location: "03101A", aisle: "3", sequence: 12476, x: 629, y: 1437 }, { area: "1", location: "03102A", aisle: "3", sequence: 12477, x: 629, y: 1485 }, { area: "1", location: "03111A", aisle: "3", sequence: 12478, x: 469, y: 1536 }, { area: "1", location: "03112A", aisle: "3", sequence: 12479, x: 469, y: 1584 }];

var retData = data.reduce(function(ret, current) {
    ret[current.aisle] = ret[current.aisle] || {};
    ret[current.aisle]['maxX'] = Math.max(ret[current.aisle]['maxX'], current.x) || current.x;
    ret[current.aisle]['maxY'] = Math.max(ret[current.aisle]['maxY'], current.y) || current.y;
    ret[current.aisle]['minX'] = Math.min(ret[current.aisle]['minX'], current.x) || current.x;
    ret[current.aisle]['minY'] = Math.min(ret[current.aisle]['minY'], current.y) || current.y;
    return ret;
}, {});

console.log(retData);
```

Answer (score -2):

I would also suggest to group any 'aisle' set as object key with that aisle uniq key, where valus will contain array of objects (that set), that will sorted / ordered by your demand, such as sum of x +y and so on.